# How long does unwhipped whipped topping last in the fridge

Tags: storage-lifetime, defrosting

I have a defrosted container of frozen non-dairy whip topping (specifically, [Rich's Rich Whip](https://www.rocklandkosher.com/p-15342-rich-whip-non-dairy-topping.aspx)). How long will it last in the fridge before I whip it?

It's essentially a non-dairy substitute for cream. It comes in a frozen container. You defrost it and then whip it up to make non-dairy whipped cream. Ingredients (from the Rich Whip FAQ):

> water, high fructose corn syrup, partially hydrogenated coconut oil, partially hydrogenated palm kernel oil, contains less than 2% of the following: carbohydrate gum, sugar, polysorbate 60, polyglycerol esters of fatty acids, salt, sodium alginate, soy lecithin, artificial flavor, sodium citrate, natural flavor, colored with turmeric and annatto extracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the proper handling page on Rich's [food service page](http://richsfoodservice.com/page/tips-handling-rtw-proper-handling/158.html) for ready-to-whip products they state (in the last section) that the container should be thawed for 24-48 hours, then whipped. Any leftover liquid should not be re-frozen, but that it can be refrigerated for "up to 5 days."